# How to construct a continuous homeomorphism from $S^1$ to itself

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We know that rotation maps $f_\alpha:e^{2\pi ix}\mapsto e^{2\pi i(x+\alpha)}$ are homeomorphism. Is there any other  homeomorphism

Comment: what's a "noncontinuous" homeomorphism?

Comment: There are a gazillion homeomorphisms from $S^1$ to itself. Just play with an elastic band to see this.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow (I think you misread this or something)